# What is an appropriate text encoding?

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

The communication between my client and server was XML in UTF-8.  Recently, however, I discovered a non-UTF-8 character in the database - there's only one in the entire database.  And apparently it needs to be preserved.

But, I don't want to change all the messages between client and server to UTF-16, as they will all suddenly double in size just for one stray unicode character.

Is there a more efficient text-encoding I could use?  Perhaps one that will still transmit the majority of ASCII characters as 8 bits, but will still allow non-UTF-8 characters to be sent somehow?

Comment: Why not just manually change that one non-UTF-8 character to UTF-8?

Comment: @Matt Ball Ultimately, the character still does need to arrive at the client intact.  I could certainly manually change any non-UTF-8 characters to something else for transmission manually, and then change it back at the client end, but I thought maybe there might be an encoding that would do it for me.

Comment: @Matt: UTF-8 *is* Unicode. It encodes ASCII characters as 8-bit, and it supports whatever character you are talking about natively. There is no "non-UTF-8 character" as UTF-8 encompasses practically all characters known to man.

Comment: when you say non-UTF8 character, what precisely do you mean? It is possible to have malformed UTF8 streams (see Invalid byte sequences on wikipedia page for UTF8). If the UTF8 is malformed, then you wont be able to reencode to any other scheme.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think this is my lack of experience in this area showing through :)  I'll go back and revisit what I'm doing.

Comment: @Matt Ball @tenfour @Jimmy Sorry for the badly worded question. I was confused because my XML said "utf-8", but the character was arriving malformed - because my communication channel was corrupting that character.  Yes, I did think that UTF-8 and ASCII were the same thing!  Oops.  But thanks to your help, I've got it working now.  My communication channel was defaulting to ASCII.  I've set it to UTF-8 and now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not confuse UTF-8 and ASCII. UTF-8 *is* a Unicode encoding. If you are really supporting UTF-8, then this Unicode character will cause no issues.

If you mistakenly said you support UTF-8 when really you are only supporting ASCII, then you should aim to support UTF-8.

Comment: Apologies, when I said "however, I discovered a unicode character in the database", I meant "I discovered a non-utf-8 character".  I'll edit my question.

Comment: My point is that UTF-8 supports whatever character you found. Assuming you already determined it's not passing through correctly though, I would say you just need to make sure you are truly supporting UTF-8. Forget about UTF-16.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on text encoding and I'm still not getting it :) One person's name in the database has this character: ñ  and in Java, when I do stringToSend.getBytes(), this character is corrupted.    But if I do stringToSend.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16")), then my transmission doubles in size.

Comment: did you try `stringToSend.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`? You realize that UTF-16 cannot represent anything that UTF-8 cannot?

Comment: No, honestly I didn't realise that, I think this is my fundamental misunderstanding of the difference between the two. I think that I thought UTF-8 and Ascii were one and the same.  This question has already taught me a lot.

Comment: ñ has a valid UTF8 encoding (it is probably split over two bytes though). do you mean non-ASCII character?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a more efficient
>   text-encoding I could use? Perhaps one
>   that will transmit most ASCII
>   characters still as 8-bit?

This is *exactly* what utf-8 is.

Comment: Apologies, I should have said "Perhaps one that will still transmit the majority of ASCII characters as 8 bits, but will still allow non-UTF-8 characters to be sent somehow?".  I'll edit my question.

Comment: Then it's not an encoding you need, it's a communication channel that doesn't care what you're sending over it.  See also Jimmy's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to understand why "this character needs to be preserved".

What is the encoding of your database ? if it is UTF-8, then it probably contains only UTF-8 characters.

Do you store UTF-8 binary representations of characters in an encoding that is <> to utf-8 ?

You should stick with utf-8 and understand more thoroughly your encoding chain.

Comment: Trust me, I understand it a lot better now!  I made the mistaken assumption that it was my XML encoder or DB that was the problem, but in fact, it was my communications channel.  I thought that Java's String.getBytes() converted to UTF-8, but it wasn't - oops!

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 already supports the full Unicode catalogue and it's possibly the most efficient encoding to store western languages in Unicode. The error you discovered was not due to having an unsupported character: it was due to having an invalid character (i.e., an encoding error).

While, in theory, XML is required to contain no errors, rejecting the full data is hardly an option since there're may suppliers out there who don't care about data validity. My advice is to log invalid chars, discard them silently and later warn the supplier.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a non-UTF-8 character. UTF-8 can encode every character there is, that is, every character in Unicode. True, there are octet sequences that are not UTF-8 encodings of any character; but that's rather different. I suspect you got an error message saying that the incoming octet stream could not be decoded as UTF-8. This happens when the sender encodes data in iso-8859-1 and the recipient is expecting it to be encoded in UTF-8.